# Adding parametrically a `Null constructor to polymorphic variants

Tags: ocaml

The following type declarations do not work:

```
type 'a or_null = [ 'a | `Null ]
```

and

```
type 'a or_null = [ 'a | `Null ] constraint 'a = [> `A | `B ]
```

With the message:

> Error: The type 'a does not expand to a polymorphic variant type
>
> Hint: Did you mean `a

I would like to achieve this without using another layer in the memory representation (and in the syntax). In particular, I want to avoid using an option type such as

```
type 'a or_null = | A of 'a | Null
```

Is there a way to have such a type using only polymorphic variants? The final goal would be to write e.g. monads on `'a or_null` types. (And this is actually the tricky part.)

Comment: This looks like the `option` type–check the Flambda flags, some of them may be able to optimize away the options. See https://blog.janestreet.com/flambda/

Comment: For various other reasons, we really need to use polymorphic variants. The simplified `[> 'A | 'B ]` has actually hundreds of constructors, which may or may not be present in some of the types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Polymorphic variants cannot track the absence of a specific constructor. This implies that we cannot really write the usual bind. If we try

```
 let bind x f =
   match x with 
   | `Null -> `Null
   | x -> f x
```

we get

```
 val bind: ([> `Null] as 'a) -> ('a -> ([>`Null] as 'b)) -> 'b
```

If for readability's sake, we add the following type abbreviation

```
 type 'a m = [> `Null] as 'a
```

(which is an alternative definition of `or_null`) the previous type read as

```
val bind: 'a m -> ('a m -> 'b m) -> 'b m
```

In other words, the function argument `f` of `bind` must already handle the `` `Null `` case in its argument by itself because the type system cannot express the constraint `` x <> `Null `` in the second branch of the match.